# can we have different version of Angular in the same application

Tags: angular, webpack

Can we run different versions of angular in the same application. 
Ex: Angular 8 and Angular 6 in the same application. I know that angular loads in  a root div. My idea is to load 2 angular in 2 different root divs.
Ex: in index.html file, we have:

```
 <div id = "angular6"></div>
 <div id = "angular8"></div>
```

I want to know if we can do it and what will be the steps to achieve this.

Comment: Why? The upgrade path is pretty easy / straightforward. Are you trying to achieve something other than just a POC?

Comment: Absolutely. Its just a POC. I am aware that its pretty crazy to attempt in production.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes!**

there are 2 options I can think

1. [recommended]Use angular element (@angular/element): it will convert all your components web component and can use directly in your page, more over angular 6 and angular 8 components can communicate each other
2. Create two `main.ts` file to bootstrap both the applications in parallel. This process I think will create more problem to manage both of the application

code to bootstrap your app:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: how about the related libs in package json file.? dont we need separate environments too?

Comment: yes, all of them will be separate if you choose the 2nd option.